# Trouble figuring out why my popup gets blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I've prepared this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x9D4c/9/

Basically, a button with a fadeOut callback causes my popup to be blocked and the other without the fadeOut callback does not. What should / could I be doing differently?

Thanks for the help!

Below the code available in jsfiddle.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="anchor1">CauseBlock</a> - <a href="#" id="anchor2">Not Cause Block</a>

<div id="greenDiv" style="background-color: green;">green div</div>
```

JS:

```
// ################################################

function causeBlock() {
    causeBlockInsideFunction(function () {
        window.open("http://www.google.com/");
    });
}

function causeBlockInsideFunction(callback) {
    $("#greenDiv").fadeOut(function () {
        callback();
    });
}

// ################################################

function notCauseBlock() {
    notCauseBlockInsideFunction(function () {
        window.open("http://www.google.com/");
    });    
}

function notCauseBlockInsideFunction(callback) {
    // [...]
    callback();
}

// ################################################

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#anchor1").click(function(e) {
        causeBlock();
    });
    $("#anchor2").click(function(e) {
        notCauseBlock();
    });
});
```

Comment: Where are you hosting jQuery, on a Google API? If the javascript doing the redirect is linked on a different domain to the one where the page is, this might be a cause an auto block.

Comment: Have reproduced on Chrome.

Comment: Well on my dev environement my jquery is hosted on my domain (or local) and on jsfiddle I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The browser prevents the JS code from automatically opening popups. This prevents having pages that automatically open hundreds of windows. So, popup opening is restricted from function calls that were triggered directly by some user interaction (a click). 
If you use an animation, the callback is called from some kind of timer which falls in the "automatic" category.

Comment: This looks like it's cause of the block. Is there a way to call jquery's fadeOut in a "synchrounous" fashion so that it won't use timers?

Comment: Not that I know of. Since this behaviour is browser dependent, I don't think there can be a workaround that will work everywhere, but maybe someone more knowledgeable will provide a solution :)